# Live PHP Ajax Search with multiple words

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, search

### Edit

I was able to solve the problem in a not so fancy way that I hoped for - but it gives the correct answers - besides very small and rare inconsistencies I hope to fix soon. If you have an idea how to make it better, please post your answer to this problem below. :)

**How I did it**

The answer was really simple. Split the search string into all its pieces using `explode` and testing every piece for title and name.

```
try{
    //$this->string is the string provided by the $_POST["string"]
    $strings = explode(" ",$this->string);
    $sql = "SELECT sithname,
           (SELECT label FROM titles WHERE id = m.title ) as titlename,
           (SELECT label FROM departments WHERE id = m.department ) as departmentname
           FROM members m
           WHERE (SELECT label FROM titles WHERE id = m.title ) LIKE :string OR sithname LIKE :string
           ORDER BY joined DESC";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    //Try every part of the string 
    foreach($strings as $key => $value){
        //This is the actual trick
        //Using LIKE + the combination of value+"%" can get you the full name, if you only type in the first letter for instance
        $stmt->execute(array(":string"=>$value.'%'));

        //If there are any rows found, save them to the $data array
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
    //Just returning the data for Ajax
    if(isset($data)){
        if($data != NULL){
        echo json_encode(array("code"=>0,"param"=>$data,"msg"=>"Matches found"));
        }else{
             echo json_encode(array("code"=>5,"param"=>"","msg"=>"No match found"));
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("code"=>5,"param"=>"","msg"=>"No match found"));
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo json_encode(array("code"=>4,"param"=>"","msg"=>$e->getCode()));
}
```

---

### Original Post

Hello there,
recently I have run into a problem and fail to wrap my head around it. Perhaps some of you have a solution or impulse.

### What I am trying to achieve

Like in Facebook - a search form where users can search for other users using their "Name", "Title", or a mixture of "Title" and "Name". For example:

SQL Data:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| name        | titlename |
+-------------+-----------+
| Seriuna Tar | Darth     |
+-------------+-----------+
| Taelax      | Darth     |
+-------------+-----------+
| Thar        | Adept     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

**If the user enters only "Darth" as input**

Results:

```
    +--------------+-----------+
    | name         | titlename |
    +--------------+-----------+
    | Seriuna Tar  | Darth     |
    +--------------+-----------+
    | Taelax       | Darth     |
    +--------------+-----------+
```

**If the user enters "Darth Seriuna T" as input**

Results:

```
    +--------------+-----------+
    | name         | titlename |
    +--------------+-----------+
    | Seriuna Tar  | Darth     |
    +--------------+-----------+
```

**!! Please note, that names can have blanks in them !!**

Because this is clearly not enough... it has to happen **LIVE**.

So as you type, results are already shown.

### What I've got so far

I've got a single text input.

```
<input id="search-bar" class="form-control mr-0 ml-0 w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
```

Via JQuery I check for changes in the text input. *(This is not the entire code, just the relevant parts)*

```
$("#search-bar").keyup(function() {
    //Check if there is valid text being typed
    if(searchtext.trim() != ""){

       //Set data that is going to be sent
        var formData = {
            'string'     : $('#search-bar').val().trim()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'php/holobook/search.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType   : 'json',
            encode      : true,
            success: function (data) {
                //Clear all previous findings
                $('.result-list').empty();

                //Go through each person found
                $.each( data["param"], function( key, value ) {
                        //Prepare a div with the userdata
                        let result = '<a class="btn btn-flat d-block text-left ml-2 p-2" href="/holobook/u/'+value["sithname"]+'">'+value["titlename"]+' '+value["sithname"]+' <small class="text-muted ml-2"> - Dark Council</small></a>';
                        //Append it to the result-list container
                        $('.result-list').append(result);

                });
                //Show the result box (like in Facebook)
                $('.result-container').show();

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log(jqXHR); //Errors
            }
        });
    }else{
        //If input is empty
        $('.result-container').hide();
        $('.result-list').empty();
    }
});
```

### Where the fun begins

Of course I can not just give the entire list of users back to the client. Filtering / Searching needs to happen on the server.

I've tried to solve it using just the SQL statement

```
   SELECT sithname, 
   (SELECT label FROM titles WHERE id = m.title ) as titlename
   FROM members m
   WHERE sithname LIKE :str OR titlename LIKE :str
   ORDER BY joined DESC
```

This is of course a fail, because it only works if title OR name is entered.

My next step was - as I had always planned - to use PHP to "filter" the results.

The data I get back looks as following *(json encoded)*:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["sithname"]=>
    string(6) "Taelax"
    ["titlename"]=>
    string(7) "Darth"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["sithname"]=>
    string(15) "Seriuna Tar"
    ["titlename"]=>
    string(7) "Darth"
  }
}
```

So to access it via foreach you need

```
foreach($results as $key => $value){
   //code
}
```

So do you have any idea how I could get to the data I need? Seems I have to split words up into single letters, then use their positions to check for matches?

Thank you very much for taking your time - if you have any idea I'm glad about every little hint.

Comment: How about you split the str with space and check for 'LIKE' with every substring using OR?

Comment: Your SQL appears to be correct, what results are you getting that are not what you expect? Why is it a fail if only a name or title is entered?

Comment: Dave, because if I enter "Darth Taelax" it does not work. Splitting the string using space and checking with like seems like a great idea though. Gonna try that :D

Comment: Your idea works, Lucifyer ;) Thank you! Updated my post.